# Populating JSON to C# Class and vice versa

Tags: json, class, serialization, json.net

I have a JSON structure from an existing REST API that I use to populate different classes using Newtonsoft.Json (JSON.Net).

I want to create a wizard that will populate the same REST API JSON structure.

The problem that I have is that my Class naming convention is different from the API JSON naming convention.

My question is: should I make my class with the same naming convention as the REST API JSON structure to make use of the `jsonconvert.serializeobject` or should I just create a JSON string that will match the JSON structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would offer a third option.  You can mark your class properties with `[JsonProperty]` attributes to match them to differently-named JSON properties.  In this way you would not need to change your JSON nor the naming convention in your classes.  Here's a simple example:

JSON:

```
{
    "item-identifier": 1234,
    "item-name": "foo"
}
```

Class definition:

```
public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("item-identifier")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("item-name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

To deserialize:

```
Item item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(json);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bwa1SM

Comment: Thank you so much Brian. Works like a charm.

Comment: I just want to add for other readers that to exclude a property you can add 

[JsonIgnore]